# Java - How can I make Array of objects of a class and call a constructor having two arguments

Tags: java

I want to know that if I can create an array of objects of a class in java so that a constructor can be invoked having two or more arguments.
For example take a look at my code -

The main class is :

```
package staticfunction;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String args[]){

    String name;
    int marks;
    int ch;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    StaticClass[] object = new StaticClass[10];  //Array of objects initalisation

    System.out.print("How many students : ");
    ch = input.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i<ch; i++){
        System.out.print("\nEnter the name of student : ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("\nEnter marks of %s", name);
        marks = input.nextInt();

        /*What should be the code here so that I can invoke a parametrized constructor*/

    }       
}

}
```

And my StaticClass is :

```
package staticfunction;

public class StaticClass {

private String name_student;
private int marks_student;
private static int count;

StaticClass(String name, int marks){
    name_student = name;
    marks_student = marks;
    count ++;

    System.out.printf("Name of student is : %s having marks : %d. Total strength of class is : %d", name_student, marks_student, count);
}

}
```

Comment: how is c++ relevant here?

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate a class? `new StaticClass(name, marks);` Assign the result of that to the appropriate array element.

Comment: I am asking that how can I invoke the constructor of StaticClass having two arguments with the help of array of objects.

Comment: That array is irrelevant to the instantiation of `StaticClass`.

Comment: That means I have to create a seprate function in StaticClass ?

Comment: And you shouldn't allocate the array until *after* you've learned how many students (`ch`, weird name) is needed.

Comment: No, just `new StaticClass(name, marks)`. That statement is a new instance creation expression. That's all you need to create a new `StaticClass` instance using its constructor that accepts 2 arguments.

Comment: The statement you're looking for, is `object[i] = new StaticClass(name, marks);`, as @SotiriosDelimanolis already told you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: Essentially, you have to think of the array as a bunch of placeholders for objects. You will not have an object at that element until you instantiate it using the constructor `object[i] = new StaticClass(name, marks);` and replace the placeholder with an actual object, as @Andreas and @SotiriosDelimanolis have said. 

When you make the array, you are simply telling the computer to put aside enough "memory slots" per se for the specified number of objects. Thus why you need to invoke the constructor for each element. Otherwise, that element will be initialized to `null`.

Comment: Also, this is the reason, as noted by @Andreas, that you should not not allocate the array until you have `ch`. Using something like `StaticClass students = new StaticClass[ch]` after `ch` is found will make it so that you only have the required number of allocated slots, and prevent trying to initialize a non-existent array index if `ch > 10`

Answer (score 1):

First of all. You named your class `StaticClass`. If you are going to make all methods static in this class there is no use in creating any objects. And you will also not be able to use the `count` variable as you are probably going to want.

To create and add instances of your class in the array just simply add this:

```
for(int i=0; i<ch; i++){
    System.out.print("\nEnter the name of student : ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("\nEnter marks of %s", name);
    marks = input.nextInt();

    object[i] = new StaticClass(name, marks);

}
```

And because you need the tell the array what size it is going to have when you instantiate it you will have to give it the same size as the given input

```
System.out.print("How many students : ");
ch = input.nextInt();
StaticClass[] object = new StaticClass[ch];  //Array of objects initalisation
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an array in java you would need to know exactly how many elements you have before you declare it. this is because an array is a block of contiguous memory, once you allocate it, you can not add to it later.
one (bad) approach you could do is declare a very large array and only fill it in partially.

Alternatively you can forgo declaring the array of StaticClass objects in the beginning of the program and only declaring it after the user provides you with the number of entries they wish to provide.

However this would be a good time for you to use an ArrayList, which is a container type that allows you to grow and shrink it as you need.

You can use the following approach:

```
package staticfunction;
import java.util.*; //imports ArrayList

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String args[]){

    String name;
    int marks;
    int ch;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many students : ");
    ch = input.nextInt();

    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList(); //create your container.

        for(int i=0; i<ch; i++){
            System.out.print("\nEnter the name of student : ");
            name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("\nEnter marks of %s", name);
            marks = input.nextInt();

            myArrayList.add(new StaticClass(name,marks)); //make a new StaticClass instance and push it to your container;
        }       

        //your ArrayList now holds the objects.

    // you can get the first element:
    StaticClass firstElement= myArrayList.get(0);

    //you can get the last element:
    StaticClass lastElement= myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-1);


    //iterate through all elements:
   for(int i=0; i<myArrayList.size(); i++)
   {
        StaticClass current=myArrayList.get(i);
        //do something with current here
   }

}

}
```

read up more on ArrayList, it provides a lot of safe functionality that you would not have with an array approach.

ArrayList will also eliminate the requirement from the user to know exactly how many entries they are entering in the program.